# HDF5 library version error - HDF5 ver 1.10.4

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, hdf5

I'm trying to import some packages with spyder (OS x64), Anaconda and pyton 3.x
The error is pretty famous in the internet. The solution proposed is to match the version of the library 1.10.5 with the HDF5 (mine is 1.10.4)

The question is that I can't find HDF5 version 1.10.5
and, the other hand, cannot understand what I could downgrade.

At this link: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/hdf5 seems exist version 1.10.5 but when I type in the prompt of anaconda `conda install -c conda-forge hdf5`
the version remain 1.10.4.

Here the warning:

```
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
=================================

General Information:
‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑
HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
Configured on: 2019
Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
Host system: Windows.0.17763
Uname information: Windows
Byte sex: little‑endian
Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5

Compiling Options:
‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑
Build Mode: 
Debugging Symbols: 
Asserts: 
Profiling: 
Optimization Level: 

Linking Options:
‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑
Libraries: 
Statically Linked Executables: OFF
LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
H5_LDFLAGS: 
AM_LDFLAGS: 
Extra libraries: 
Archiver: 
Ranlib: 

Languages:
‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑
C: yes
C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
CPPFLAGS: 
H5_CPPFLAGS: 
AM_CPPFLAGS: 
CFLAGS: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
H5_CFLAGS: 
AM_CFLAGS: 
Shared C Library: YES
Static C Library: YES

Fortran: OFF
Fortran Compiler: 
Fortran Flags: 
H5 Fortran Flags: 
AM Fortran Flags: 
Shared Fortran Library: YES
Static Fortran Library: YES

C++: ON
C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
H5 C++ Flags: 
AM C++ Flags: 
Shared C++ Library: YES
Static C++ Library: YES

JAVA: OFF
JAVA Compiler: 

Features:
‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑‑
Parallel HDF5: OFF
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: 
Large Parallel I/O: 
High‑level library: ON
Threadsafety: OFF
Default API mapping: v110
With deprecated public symbols: ON
I/O filters (external): DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
MPE: 
Direct VFD: 
dmalloc: 
Packages w/ extra debug output: 
API Tracing: OFF
Using memory checker: OFF
Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
Function Stack Tracing: OFF
Strict File Format Checks: OFF
Optimization Instrumentation: 
Bye...
```

Here all the packages installed:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Megaport\Anaconda3\envs\venv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl
absl-py                   0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
astor                     0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1
attrs                     19.1.0                   py37_1
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     1
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_1
cffi                      1.12.3           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
cloudpickle               1.2.1                      py_0
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
cryptography              2.7              py37h7a1dbc1_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.19                     py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.2            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.8.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10.1                   py37_0
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                3.0.2                    py37_0
jupyter_client            5.3.1                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0
keras                     2.2.4                         0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-base                2.2.4                    py37_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37ha925a31_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.2            py37he774522_0
libmklml                  2019.0.5                      0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.8.0                h7bd577a_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libxgboost                0.90                          0
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37hc8f65d3_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mistune                   0.8.4            py37he774522_0
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.0.2            py37he774522_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h343c172_0
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
numpy                     1.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.16.4           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1
opt-einsum                3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 19.1                     py37_0
pandas                    0.25.1           py37ha925a31_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pip                       19.2.2                   py37_0
pluggy                    0.12.0                     py_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0
protobuf                  3.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.6.3            py37he774522_0
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0
py-xgboost                0.90                     py37_0
py-xgboost-cpu            0.90                     py37_0
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0
pytest                    5.0.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0
pytz                      2019.2                     py_0
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37he774522_0
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37ha925a31_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.5.7                    py37_1
qtconsole                 4.5.4                      py_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h29ff71c_0
setuptools                41.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
snowballstemmer           1.9.0                      py_0
sphinx                    2.1.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.5.1                    py37_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               he774522_0
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0
tb-nightly                1.15.0a20190806          pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37he3c9ec2_0
tensorflow                1.14.0          mkl_py37h7908ca0_0
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          mkl_py37ha978198_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
tornado                   6.0.3            py37he774522_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.6                   pypi_0    pypi
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zipp                      0.5.2                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
```

Anyway, I don't understand why in the prompt HDF5 is version 1.10.4 and in the warning, version of HDF5 is 1.10.5

Comment: Note the message says _Headers_ are **1.10.4**, _library_ is **1.10.5**. I manage everything in the conda environemnt, and have not run into this problem (and I use spyder). I have hdf5 version 1.10.4 / build         h7ebc959_0. Are you using conda package manager for all Python packages? The error message looks like Visual Studio compiler. How did you install the HDF5 library? Is it possible you have HDF5 library versions from different sources (for Python and C)?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. 
1) same version and build. 
2) I'm using Anaconda Navigator and sometimes prompt of anaconda
3) I've installed HDF5 by prompt with "conda install hdf5"
4) I'm using only R and Spyder. 

I'm trying to check Visual Studio compiler as you said

Comment: After reading closer, I'm a little bit confused. Are you getting the first error message when running `conda install -c conda-forge hdf5`? If so, why do you need to install another version of the HDF5 package? You already have it in your conda environment (as indicated by the second output).

Comment: In the meanwhile I've tryied:
Removed the env.
Created a new one. Installed all the packages and then installed spyder inside the env. It works now, really don't know what happened. Thanx for your help

Comment: I suspect you have HDF5 libraries installed in 2 places and the conda environment was "confused". Conda has 1.10.4. You have to get 1.10.5 from the HDF5 group (which installs into C:/Program Files/HDF5 by default). This is consistent with the first error message. Using conda to remove and reinstall is the way to go. There is a github posting on this same topic: (https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/853)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe I am late, but I resolved this problem by upgrading hdf5 to 1.10.5.

On Windows 10, with anaconda you can do this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge hdf5=1.10.5
```

Comment: My friend, I've been all day trying to solve it. Tried almost everything, and then I found your answer and decided to give a shot. You don't imagine my relief when it worked. Thank you <3

Answer (score 11):

I'll leave this here, since it's a top stack thread for me without clear answer.

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py
```

If you are using conda to install tensorflow it installs h5py with 1.10.5 version and on top installs hdf5 1.10.4. Creating conflict that resolves after pip "juggling" since 1.10.4 satisfies the latest h5py.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Windows 10. Here is what I did

1. Install some requirements for TensorFlow > 2.0
   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang
2. Create conda virtual environment:

```
conda create -n ai python==3.7.6
conda activate ai
conda install pandas matplotlib scikit-learn scrapy seaborn
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

I had following same issue.

Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.6

My solution is making another conda environment and do every conda w/ 'conda-forge'.
Since hdf5 1.10.4 was installed with following command on my win10 PC w/ no GPU. Python is 3.7.10.

conda install tensorflow

By above command, 1.10.4 came with.
So, I should have done following.

conda install conda-forge tensorflow

Then, 1.10.6 was installed.
'conda-forge' w/ conda install is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. It came about because the tensorflow was installed by conda. And the error disappears when using channel anaconda.

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem when I realized (on Mac OSX Mojave) that I had used Homebrew to install Octave, which was built to work with HDF5 1.10.5. I first ran in to this issue trying to install and run TensorFlow from iPython. I'm not actively using Octave, so I uninstalled Octave as well as HDF5 with

```
brew uninstall --force octave
brew uninstall hdf5
```

Then upon re-running

```
conda install h5py
```

and subsequently importing TensorFlow from iPython, everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple tensorflow code sum.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(1, name="a")
b = tf.Variable(2, name="b")
f = a + b

tf.print("The sum of a and b is", f)
```

===
I am window 10 user with Anaconda 3, tensorflow 2.0, jupyter, and pyhton 3.
I have similiar issues and i resovle the following iusses:
Error:
UserWarning: h5py is running against HDF5 1.10.5 when it was built against 1.10.4, this may cause problems

My environment was messad up with lots of pip install.
The following video resolve my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgO8BBNGB8w&t=376s

It uses the tensorflow.yml with a list of clean environment:

https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning

Under the window prompt:

> conda env create -v -f tensorflow

Then open anaconda prompt

> conda acticate tensorflow
> python sum.py
> or in jupyter notebook. run with OK.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed tensorflow via

> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

I resolved it as follows:

I uninstalled h5py and tensorflow by:

> pip uninstall h5py
>
> conda uninstall h5py
>
> conda uninstall tensorflow

and reinstalled tensorflow by:

> conda install -c anaconda tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Damn I had the same error shown in the anaconda prompt and the reason believe me is really silly.

I was multi-tasking and I `forgot to activate the environment` which resulted in two different versions of HDF5.

Please make sure to `conda activate environment_name` before launching the jupyter notebook.